# Why aren't these white lines disapearing?

Tags: body-work, paint-scratches

I scraped a high kerb and this left some white lines\marks\scratch on my car.  I wiped the area and then sprayed it repeatedly with black however the white lines are just not going.

I also applied t-cut however that didn't make any difference either.

Can you tell me what this white lines\scratches in the picture and why spraying with black isnt removing it?

I was using phantom black rather than the cars ebony black but i dont think that should leave those lines there? The phantom black did fine in other parts of the car.
I also didnt apply clear coat, polish or wax but I don't think its needed, just to hide those marks surely black spray is enough as a first step and I i dont need a professional job.

What are the marks\lines in the lower part of the car and why aren't they being covered by spray? how can I fix it.

Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell in the photo but could the "lines" actually be cracks in the sill itself? If that were the case then no amount of spraying will make them go away without filling them first.

Another possibility is that the pray paint is struggling (and failing) to adhere to the surface where the scratches are, many automotive paints are designed to adhere either to clean primer or to clean layers of themselves and will simply slide easily off layers of set clear coat etc.